# How to plot: $\int - \frac {W(-\ln x)}{\ln x} dx$?

Tags: plotting, numerical-integration

How would we plot: $$\int - \frac {W(-\ln x)}{\ln x} dx$$
Where $W$ is the [Lambert W function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)?

Comment: Is `LambertW` easily found in the docs? I couldn't find anything about it.

Comment: `LambertW` is an alias for `ProductLog`.

Comment: I don't really know anything about this topic, but isn't this the same as `PolyLog`? (See the diagram when you search for `ReImPlot`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Put this all [here](https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/49925470#49925470) but this works:

```
lambs =
  Quiet@
   Table[
    {x, NIntegrate[-LambertW[-Log[y]]/Log[y], {y, .1, x},
      MaxRecursion -> 200]},
    {x, 0, 1.6, .01}
    ];

ListLinePlot[lambs]
```

If you take this out to `x=10` and plot both the real and imaginary parts:

```
ListLinePlot[
 {
  Re@lambs,
  Transpose[{lambs[[All, 1]], Im@lambs[[All, 2]]}]
  }
 ]
```

[image: asdasd]

Answer (score 2):

```
 f[x_] := NIntegrate[-LambertW[-Log[y]]/Log[y], {y, .1, x}]
 Plot[{Re[f[x]], Im[f[x]]}, {x, 0, 10}]
```

[image]